# jQuery scrollLeft not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I just launched http://elliewauters.com & have a little problem that I'd like to fix, the site uses a lot of animated horizontal scrolling to go from one 'page' to the next, but on refresh most browsers remember the scroll position & go back to where I was before, I do not want this. Try going to the 'About' page & then refreshing. You'll see that the logo & menu are in the middle of the page as they where when you arrived at the site for the first time.

**I would like help with either of two things:**

1. To reset the scroll position back to 0,0 on page refresh OR
2. To move the logo & menu to the top if the scrollLeft value is greater than 1.

I have tried using `$(window).scrollLeft(0);` to no avail &

```
scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
console.log(scrollLeft)
if (scrollLeft>1) {
    $('#header').addClass('notLeft').css('top','0%');
} else {
    $('#header').addClass('left').css('top','25%');
}
```

does not work, does anyone please have an idea of how I could achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just an idea:
I am not sure if it will work but you can try to catch this 'refresh' in onleave and reset it at that point?

Comment: The header doesn't move at all in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well Firefox wasn't working because of the `console.log(scrollLeft)` so it should work after removing that. As for the problem you are having, I'm guessing it is only happening in IE? The solution is to not use `$(window)` but instead replace it with `$(document)`. So use:

```
scrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
```

Comment: I kept the console.log but added a semicolon to the end which I omitted by mistake. Changing to '$(document)' makes everything work but only in Firefox, any ideas why it doesn't work in webkit?

Comment: Not sure, but `console.log` is only valid if firebug is working... try completely removing it and then test.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but .scrollLeft() in jQuery didn't work for me on Android, too, under jQuery 1.9.1 today (April, 2013). Try this:

```
window.scrollTo(x, y);
```

This worked for me on all recent platforms and OS's, including Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#el").animate({ scrollLeft:110 }, "fast");
```