# Scroll Page Horizontally With Mouse Wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

Im doing an horizontal scroll page using this tutorial (mousewheel plugin and script):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

The scroll works on chrome but not on firefox, it doesn´t work on firefox in the tutorial also, any ideas how to fix it?

```
$(function() {
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928848/jquery-scrollleft-not-working

It looks like you need to perhaps use $(document).scrollLeft instead.

Comment: by "it doesnt work" I mean, that it doesnt work on firefox.......

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663525/jquery-animate-scrollleft-bug-in-ie-and-ff

Answer (score 2):

http://cobbweb.me/blog/2012/03/30/jquery-mousewheel-plugin-version-2/

This plugin might help you to get mousewheel scroll working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is some scroll plugin can help you.
https://github.com/lvming6816077/H5FullscreenPage